# Locally Stored Image is not displaying in IOS Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, java-native-interface, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I have a  cordova hybrid app that has to display image from local file. But its not displaying the images.

Using filetransfer plugin images are getting downloaded in local document folder with help of phonegap.

Source Code for Image Download using PhoneGap

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry;
String rootDir;
String localfilepath;
String uri = servlet get the uri 

FileTransfer fileTransfer = phoneGap.getFile().createFileTransfer();

phoneGap.getFile().requestFileSystem(FileSystem.LocalFileSystem_PERSISTENT, 5 * 1024 * 1024, new FileCallback<FileSystem, FileError>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final FileSystem fileSystem) {
        rootDir = entry.getRoot().toURL();
        final Flags create = new Flags(true, false);
        // creating folder SampleFile
        fileSystem.getRoot().getDirectory("SampleFile", create, new FileCallback<DirectoryEntry, FileError>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DirectoryEntry entry) {

        directoryEntry = entry;

        entry.getFile("welcome.jpg", create, new FileCallback<FileEntry, FileError>() {
                                            
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final FileEntry entry1) {
                        
        //file created
                                        
                        }
                }
        }
    }
}

    fileTransfer.download(uri, directoryEntry.toURL()+"/"+"welcome.jpg", new 
    FileDownloadCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileEntry result) {
    localfilepath = rootDir+result.getFullPath()    //This  my local file path

    }

  }
```

//Finally setting the local file path in  image field

```
Image contentImage = new Image();
contentImage.setSize("200px", "200px");
contentImage.setUrl(localfilepath);
```

Above code is not displaying the image . For android its working fine but for ios iam facing problem.This my local file path

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9DAC70D-36AD-42BE-930C-644514B/Documents/SampleFile/welcome.jpg

Bascially UI developed in GWT(Google Web Tool Kit). For accessing FileSystem iam using PhoneGap For Build IOS App iam using Cordova

I tried lot but still is not working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks .

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem using Cordova 11-- images work on Android and iOS simulator, but not on physical iPhone SE running iOS 15.4 .

Comment: @JamesMarshall did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Matt I couldn't successfully set an image.src to a "file:" URL, but I found an imperfect workaround:  Create a Blob from the file contents, use URL.createObjectURL(blob) to get a "blob:" URL, and set image.src to that.  It's more efficient than simply converting all file contents to "data:" URLs, but you still need to load images into Blobs for every run before referencing them ("blob:" URLs aren't persistent).  If some images will be used multiple times, you can cache the created "blob:" URLs in a hash keyed by e.g. the image path.

Comment: Also note that on physical iPhones, the full path to the app and its files will change every time the app is updated.  This does not happen on Android or the iOS simulator.

Comment: @Matt here's the complete solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72428906/2573393