# In Cordova app, physical iPhone SE can't display images from "file://" URLs; OK in iOS simulator and Android

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova-ios

I'm writing an app with Cordova 11.0.0, cordova-ios 6.2.0, and Xcode 13.3 that sets the background image to the user's choice.  Everything works fine on Android and on the iOS simulator.  However, when running on a physical iPhone SE (2022) with iOS 15.4, the background image is not displayed, though it seems to set `style.backgroundImage` correctly on the element, and I'm able to read the image file correctly using a standard FileReader object.  It appears that any local images using a `file://` URL are not displayed.  I'm loading them from under `cordova.file.dataDirectory`, so I can't just convert to a relative `http://` URL.  I believe my `Content-Security-Policy` is permissive enough (?) (see `index.html` below).

I made a small demo of this; the only plugin it uses is cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2.  My `config.xml` contains:

```
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
        <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
    </platform>
```

My `index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
            content="default-src * file: filesystem: ; img-src * file: filesystem: ; style-src * file: filesystem: 'unsafe-eval' ;">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Background image should show up</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

My `index.js` is:

```
// Wait for the deviceready event before using any of Cordova's device APIs.
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

async function onDeviceReady() {
    try{
        // this block just copies file from under cordova.file.applicationDirectory
        //   to under cordova.file.dataDirectory, for this demo
        // FileEntry.copyTo() throws error on ios if file already exists, so use try/catch
        try {
            let entry= await new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
                resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/img/home_bg.jpg',
                    resolve, reject) ) ;
            let dest_dir= await new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
                resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, resolve, reject) ) ;
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                entry.copyTo(dest_dir, undefined, resolve, reject) ) ;
        } catch(e) {}

        // set full background property
        let full_url= cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'home_bg.jpg' ;
        document.body.style.background= 'url(' + full_url + ') center/cover' ;

        // this shows the correct 'url("file:///Users/.../Library/NoCloud/home_bg.jpg")'
        alert('computed backgroundImage=[' + getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundImage + ']') ;

    } catch(e) {
        alert('in odr(): '+e) ;
    }
}
```

My `index.css` is simply:

```
body {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
}

h1 {
    font-size:24pt;
    margin:3rem;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And finally, I have a background image in `img/home_bg.jpg` that is copied to be under `cordova.file.dataDirectory`.

I've read many questions here about `file://` URLs, but none of the solutions have worked and are appropriate (e.g. using `data:` URLs for the images is impractical and unscalable).  I know that the app paths change for every install on an iPhone, but the code above should still work.

How can I get images to display on a physical iPhone using `file://` URLs?  Am I missing some setting in Xcode or elsewhere?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57331418/25733930) by @jcbdrn,  I managed to work around this by using `blob:` URLs for all displayed images:

```
let blob= new Blob([await read_file_binary(file_entry)]) ;
img.src= URL.createObjectURL(blob) ;
```

... where `read_file_binary()` reads a file as an arrayBuffer.  Note that the Content Security Policy must include `blob:` in the `img-src` directive.

This isn't as efficient as just using `file:` URLs, but it's much better than using `data:` URLs.  It does seem like a bug in either `cordova-ios` (?) or in WKWebView (?), but I'm set for now.